# Ruby Model Relationships - Three way Relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have an app that has 3 specific models; User, Country and City. The ideal relationship for each would be as follow:

**User**

- has_many :countries
- has_many :cities, through: :country

**Country**

- has_many :users
- has_many :cities

**City**

- has_many :users
- belongs_to :country

Most of those relationships are fairly straight forward, however, the User-to-City relationship is giving me a bit of a problem. I want to be able to assign a city to a user, as long as the user has been assigned to the country associated to the city. Right now I am not even able to assign a user a city, let alone institute the correct logic for the restriction.

So far what I have been able to read and search has led to the below.

**User.rb**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

  before_save { self.email = email.downcase}
  #attr_accessible :username, :email
  validates_confirmation_of :password
  has_secure_password

  validates :username, presence: true, length: { maximum: 25 }, uniqueness: {case_sensitive: false}
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(\.[a-z\d\-]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 }, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }
  validates :password, presence: true, confirmation: true, length: { minimum: 6 }
  validates :password_confirmation, presence: true

  has_many :trips
  has_many :countries, through: :trips
  has_many :cities, through: :trips

end
```

**Country.rb**

```
class Country < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :trips
  has_many :cities
  has_many :users, through: :trips

end
```

**City.rb**

```
class City < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :trips
  belongs_to :country

end
```

**Trip.rb**

```
class Trip < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :country
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :city

end
```

Comment: Could you just create two standard joins tables: `countries_users` and `cities_users`, and write a **model validation** on the latter to assert that the city has been assigned to the user?

Comment: Side note: You presumably also require some sort of pre- or post- deletion logic to prevent a user being **un-assigned** from a country, yet still remain assigned to the cities. (i.e. Either disallow such deletions, or delete the other associations as part of the transaction.)

Comment: You can't assign a city to a user as a user has_many cities? A user needs to belongs_to a city in order for to be able to assign a city to a user! What you really want is to assign visits to users and assign a city to a visit. Update your question to one that makes sense and maybe I can help further. Scrap the simplification it's causing you problems and making you think you should be able to do things that break your requirements

Answer (score 0):

> want to be able to assign a city to a user, as long as the user has
>   been assigned to the country associated to the city

You can't and nor should you want to.

Create a country. Create a city and assign it to a country. Create a trip or a visit, assign that visit or a trip to a city then add users to that trip or visit. Voila! you have the relationship you need! I think.

A city belongs_to a country
A trip belongs_to a city
A visit belongs_to a city
A user has_many visits
A user has_many trips
Because both trips and visits belongs to a city you can have has_many through relationships on both sides of the join therefore the visits and trips tables need both city and user id's
And you have the relationships you need and the logic you need.

Don't try to do things that break your requirements like join cities to users directly as there is no way a city can be assigned to a user. Indeed just to give you an even bigger headache you may even want to have trips taking in many visits to many cities in many countries. In which case you want visits to be assigned to a trip not a city.

This is a logic problem not a coding issue.

UPDATE In response to comments

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :trips
  has_many :cities, through: :trips
end

class Trip < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :city
end

class City < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :trips
  has_many :users, through: :trips
end
```

then in console

```
Loading development environment (Rails 5.1.4)
2.4.0 :001 > u = User.create(name: "Fred")
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("name", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?)  [["name", "Fred"], ["created_at", "2017-09-17 14:24:30.720005"], ["updated_at", "2017-09-17 14:24:30.720005"]]
   (16.3ms)  commit transaction
 => #<User id: 1, name: "Fred", created_at: "2017-09-17 14:24:30", updated_at: "2017-09-17 14:24:30"> 
2.4.0 :004 > c = City.create(name: "Leeds")
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "cities" ("name", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?)  [["name", "Leeds"], ["created_at", "2017-09-17 14:26:19.293166"], ["updated_at", "2017-09-17 14:26:19.293166"]]
   (33.9ms)  commit transaction
 => #<City id: 1, name: "Leeds", created_at: "2017-09-17 14:26:19", updated_at: "2017-09-17 14:26:19"> 
2.4.0 :005 > t = Trip.create(name: "T1", user: u, city: c) 
   (0.2ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO "trips" ("user_id", "city_id", "name", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["user_id", 1], ["city_id", 1], ["name", "T1"], ["created_at", "2017-09-17 14:28:44.656390"], ["updated_at", "2017-09-17 14:28:44.656390"]]
   (26.0ms)  commit transaction
 => #<Trip id: 1, user_id: 1, city_id: 1, name: "T1", created_at: "2017-09-17 14:28:44", updated_at: "2017-09-17 14:28:44"> 
2.4.0 :006 > t.user.name#
 => "Fred" 
2.4.0 :007 > t.city.name
 => "Leeds" 
2.4.0 :008 > t.name
 => "T1"
```

So that's how a normal has_many through works but you want a has_many cities on the trips model so I'll update how that would work shortly

OK, to achieve the next stage where a trip has many cities and a city has_many trips note the has_many on BOTH sides of the relationship you are going to need a new cross reference table probably called trip_city_xref that has a compound primary key of city_id and trip_id

This is in Rails terms is a has_and_belongs_to_many relationship which I hate. It is my opinion only that the has_and_belongs_to_many was about the only thing Rails got wrong. It's a short cut. Others will disagree but this is how I would set this up in a language that does not have that short cut. I think it is clearer and less ambiguous. So I would set up something like this

```
class Trip < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to: :city_trip_xref and  
  has_many :cities, through: :city_trip_xref
end

class City < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :trips, through: :city_trip_xref
  has_many :users, through: :trips
end

class CityTripXref < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :trip
  belongs_to :city
end
```

That is just my opinion so feel free to go read up on has_and_belongs_to_many [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has-many-through-and-has-and-belongs-to-many)
So what do you do with your user now? Again, I'll update shortly

UPDATE User.cities
So your user model could look like this

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :trips
  has_many :city_trip_xrefs, through: :trips
  def cities
    trips.map(&:city_trip_xrefs).flatten.map(&:city)
  end
end
```

To get all the cities a user is visiting on a trip you can flatten and map the relations like so
u = User.first
u.trips.map(&:city_trip_xrefs).flatten.map(&:city)

So you could make a method on your user class to get the cities using the above as shown in the user model above. As for allocating a city to a user, well you wouldn't really want to do that directly anyway. You would set up a trip, add users and cities to that trip and then you have all the functionality you are likely to need in a real world example unless your requirements are somewhat different

Putting it all together using the above created records in the console plus a record in the city_trip_xref table to join the many to many trips to cities for the one existing city and trip you can now do

First create the xref in the console

```
 ctx = CityTripXref.new
 => #<CityTripXref id: nil, city_id: nil, trip_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil> 
2.4.0 :008 > ctx.city = City.first
 => #<City id: 1, name: "Leeds", created_at: "2017-09-17 14:26:19", updated_at: "2017-09-17 14:26:19"> 
2.4.0 :009 > ctx.trip = Trip.first
 => #<Trip id: 1, user_id: 1, city_id: 1, name: "T1", created_at: "2017-09-17 14:28:44", updated_at: "2017-09-17 14:28:44"> 
2.4.0 :010 > ctx.save
```

next get the name of the first city on the first trip for the first user

```
2.4.0 :028 > u = User.first
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
 => #<User id: 1, name: "Fred", created_at: "2017-09-17 14:24:30", updated_at: "2017-09-17 14:24:30"> 
2.4.0 :029 > u.cities.first.name
  Trip Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "trips".* FROM "trips" WHERE "trips"."user_id" = ?  [["user_id", 1]]
  CityTripXref Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "city_trip_xrefs".* FROM "city_trip_xrefs" WHERE "city_trip_xrefs"."trip_id" = ?  [["trip_id", 1]]
  City Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "cities".* FROM "cities" WHERE "cities"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
 => "Leeds" 
2.4.0 :030 >
```

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Okay so to avoid added confusion (mostly on my part) I have taken away the Visit model. I have edited my code above to what I think you are suggesting. It still does not work, I cannot assign `user1.cities << [city1]`, but it looks close.

Comment: Course you can't. You need to go through trips. I don;t think you really understand what it is you want to do. I will update my answer shortly with how what you have set up should work. But I still don't think it's what you want. Personally I'd come back to this after I'd written a UML use case or at least written out a spec